# jQuery Selectric bug on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ipad, jquery-selectric

I use jQuery Selectric plugin for customize select's.

```
$('select').selectric({
  disableOnMobile: false
});
```

If i open select on iPad device my left column move up

```
.left-column {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #F00;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Please, help with it. Demo here: http://output.jsbin.com/seleyi

[image]

**UPD:** test at browserstack iOS < 7 - no problem, iOS 8.3 - have some problem, iOS 9.1 have this bug

Comment: `100vh` → `100%` : http://output.jsbin.com/hiyewotiqo

Comment: @blex it help in this example, but not on my site, i make new demo, here you can catch it if select place in bottom of page http://jsbin.com/seleyi/edit?output http://prntscr.com/a8k00x

Comment: @blex i add demo and picture in question

Comment: In ipad2 Safari i do not see the problem

Comment: @silviagreen you right, now test at browserstack iOS < 7 - no problem, iOS 8.3 - have some problem, iOS 9.3 have this bug

Comment: iOS 9.3 is beta and released on January 14, 2016 -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_9

Comment: and according to this you cant even use the Beta versions unless you are a developer -- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203282 -- so its not released an update

Comment: @Tasos thank you it's my make a mistake, i mean iOS 9.1

Comment: no probs. so by the sounds of it with latest  IOS updates (iOS 8.3 - have some problem, iOS 9.1 have this bug) the issue is getting worse and worse -- there should be another update soon so maybe they wll  fix that issue by then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's bug iOS 9, include in iOS 8, but in 9 version include partly.

Bug with `input`, with attribute `readonly="readonly"`. Selectric use hide input:

[image]

What happen:

1. If click on `selectric-wrapper` start method `_open`.
2. Method `_open` set focus on hide `input.selectric-input`. It make selectric plugin and i don't know why. May be, more simple add listeners for keystrokes on a hidden element. And handle such events when an item has focus. Why `input`? If you use another element, then pressing the arrow keys, we will also scroll the document itself. Because, use input , although I could be wrong. Maybe better input for e-readers, ie, used it to enhance accessibility.

And when focus comes to input , despite the fact that it is readonly, iOS (I think so) tries to allocate space for the keyboard. I can advise a simple workaround:

```
$(".selectric-input[readonly]").on("focus", function(evt) {
    this.blur();
});
```

Ie when the focus input immediately rid of him, because on iPads impossible to move through the list using the keyboard, the functionality should not be compromised.